# wrote query same method in different way

Tags: mysql, sql

what is **difference** between this queries.. I thought both queries giving `same result` could you check this queries..

```
select kgfs,
       count(case when loan_disbursement_date between '2015-04-01' and '2016-03-31' then urn else 0 end) as count
from all_cms_loans_dump_unique
where kgfs <> '' and
      urn <> ''
group by kgfs;




select kgfs, count(urn)
from all_cms_loans_dump_unique
where loan_disbursement_date between '2016-04-01' and '2017-03-31' and
      kgfs <> '' and
      urn <> ''
group by kgfs;
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference is that the first version will return counts of `0` and the second will not.  These rows will be filtered out.

There might also be a difference in performance, because the first might need to aggregate more data than the second.  On the other hand, the first is guaranteed to return all values of `kgfs`, even if there are no matching records.

Answer (score 0):

The important point here (apart from the different years in your dates) is that `count(value)` counts everything with a value that is `not null`.

```
select count(0) from table
```

will give you the number of rows in the table, while

```
select count(null) from table
```

will give you `0`.

You want the second behaviour. Remove `else 0` (or replace it with `else null`) in your first query to get a similar result to your second one.

They are still just similar, not equal, because, as Gordon pointed out, for values of `kgfs` that are in the table, but have no date in range, in your first query you will get a row `<kgfs>, 0` in the result, in your second query you won't (because they are already filtered out by the `where`-statement).

Comment: Thanks folks..valid for me